# Installing older versions of timescaledb for postgresql on macos

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x, timescaledb

I'm running `postgresql 14.1` on `MacOs Monterey`, this was installed as a requirement of `timescaledb` which is at version `2.5.1`.
I had issues while installing timescaledb with another version of postgresql not installed via `brew` so i purged that installation completely and ran `brew install timescaledb` which also setup postgresql again, did the config and everything works smoothly.

Now the problem is, i have a sql_dumb that requires timescaledb extension, the thing is, even after it successfully restores the database dumb, i can't access it due to a timescaledb error

```
ERROR 58P01 (undefined_file) could not access file "$libdir/timescaledb-2.5.0": No such file or director
```

..am wondering how i can fix this,
i have tried,

- running sql commands to create extension after the database restore
- tried installing timescaledb@2.5.0 which brew did not find a formular for
- creating symlinks to the installed version of timescaledb in the `$libdir`, as required by the error above

...none seems to fix the issue, is there a way i can install timescaledb 2.5.0, any other fix to remedy my situation is also welcome

Comment: Restoring the database with -C, to clean and recreate fixed this issue

Comment: We have an ongoing challenge with homebrew as it coopts the version of Postgres which is not always useful when installing the TimescaleDB extension as you found...  ​There are some details in this issue that may help https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/3245 or you could look at using a Docker install instead?  We have also had challenges if PG was previously installed per the docs page. https://docs.timescale.com/install/latest/self-hosted/installation-macos/ Would any of these approaches work for you?

*Transparency: I work for Timescale*

Comment: @greenweeds ..thanks a lot for your comment, i had earlier resolved my issues, but the breadcrumbs you left surely led to something i had not tried
..thanks again